# read from file character by character

Tags: java, file

I have an output file in my project which contains some information like this:

```
 <Keyword: begin >

 <Keyword: for >

 <Id: i >
```

I want to read from the file line by line and add each character to a string. My code is like this:

```
tokenArr = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader input ;
String line,value="",type="";
int index=2;
char ch;

try
{   
    input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    System.out.println("File is Opened!");
    while ((line = input.readLine())!=null)
    {
        ch = line.charAt(index);
        while( ch !=' ')
        {
            value += ch;
            index++;
            ch = line.charAt(index);
        }
```

As you see, my code doesn't have a problem but when I run it I get the following error:

```
"Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1" error !
```

The index is 2 because I don't want the first 2 characters. Can you help me with this ?

Comment: You should first debug your while loop for each line. Write a SOP there and check what exactly it is printing. Seems like there is a line that doesn't have any character in it.

Answer (score 0):

You may not be resetting the index after the inner while loop. Also, what if the line doesn't contain a whitespace character at all? The inner while loop would only end when index reaches `line.length()` , thereby line.charAt() throwing a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Instead of working char by char, use the substring() methods:

```
while((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    if(line.length() > 2) {
      line = line.substring(2); //I don't want the first two chars
      if(!line.contains(" ")) {
        value += line + "\n";
        // if value were a StringBuilder value.append(line).append('\n');
      }
      else {
        value += line.substring(0, line.indexOf(" ")) + "\n";
        // StringBuilder value.append(line.substring(0, line.indexOf(" ")).append('\n');
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your while loop a little in this way:

```
while ((line = input.readLine())!=null)
{
    if (line.length() > 3 )//because you starting with index 2
    {
         ch = line.charAt(index);
         while( ch !=' ')
         {
            value += ch;
            index++;
            ch = line.charAt(index);
            index = 2; //reset index to 2
         }
    }
}
```